# AppEngine Cloud SQL Delay

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

Over the past couple of weeks we have had increase page load times on our website and while running certain pages on our AppEngine setup.

The problem comes when doing anything with the Cloud SQL Database from AppEngine.

We have narrowed down the problem by running the following test

Run the same PHP page on both Compute Engine (via Cloud SQL Proxy) and AppEngine

```
Result (Compute Engine)
 1539768438.6956 :: Starting...
 1539768438.6960 :: Set order xxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxx as printed
 1539768438.6960 :: - Updating cbd 
 1539768438.7148 :: - Updating printing_flag
 1539768438.7165 :: - Done 
Speed: 0.02 Seconds

Result (AppEngine)
 1539768392.9724 :: Starting...
 1539768392.9725 :: Set order xxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxx as printed
 1539768392.9726 :: - Updating cbd
 1539768393.1558 :: - Updating printing_flag
 1539768393.2043 :: - Done
Speed: 0.23 Seconds
```

The "Updating printing_flag" section is attempting to delete an entry that does not exist, in a table that has less than 200 rows in it, and this on AppEngine is still taking a lot of time compared to Compute Engine.

PHP Page:

```
addLog('Starting');

//Loop
 addLog('Set order ' . $o->basket_id . ' as printed');

 // Do the setting of this basket when we want it to be saved
 addLog('- Updating cbd');
 db_q("UPDATE cust_basket_detail SET basket_printed = '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."' WHERE basket_id = '".addslashes($o->basket_id)."' LIMIT 1"); // [130,000 Rows]

 addLog('- Updating printing_flag');
 db_q("DELETE FROM printing_flag WHERE basket_id = '" . addslashes($o->basket_id) . "' LIMIT 1"); // [200 Rows]


addLog('- Done');
```

These timings used to be identical until a couple of weeks ago.

There is no load on the AppEngine instance as this is a new version freshly built, and the page loaded a few times with the same result.

Is there anyone else that is experiencing latency/delays when connecting to CloudSQL from AppEngine? or is there something else we need to look into/test.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since it only started recently without code change on your end and your issue is mostly performance speed, the issue is probably best reported on our [Public Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/) page. We will be able to assist you better there, thanks.